# Java applets don't run

Tags: browser, java-applet

I have a problem with these java applets. When I go to [this](http://media.pearsoncmg.com/aw/aw_kurose_network_2/applets/transmission/delay.html) link and want to see the running java applet of this site I face below error. I disabled my AV (KIS 2013) and Windows firewall but still I can't see the applet.
Is there any way to fix that problem please?

[image]

Comment: What are your java security settings set to?  Have you tried to change the configuration?  You can do that by using the java control panel applet.

Comment: how to go to the security settings?

Answer (score 1):

Since JRE 7U51 was released in earlier this year, many java applets now need allowed explicitly in order to run in the browser.

In the Java Control Panel, add the url of the applet. More detailed Instructions here:
https://www.java.com/en/download/exception_sitelist.jsp

Comment: I did the works said in that link but no change. Please look at my updated image in the question. I entered the no.1 address into the Security tab which led to nothing and after that I tried to add no 2 link into security tab (of JAva) but it's not possible to add that!

Comment: what version of the jre do you have installed? do you recieve a message in chrome like the one indicated here? https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: My java was _Version 7 update 0_ but I downloaded last version and installed it now it's _Version 7 update 65_ and the security configuration made for previous version is also set for this new version. I can't see that applets. As I asked the problem is that what  address I should enter to the security tab. No.1 is not working and no.2 is not possible! So what can I do?

Comment: you will have to ask them for support on that front. they should be able to provide a list of domains to allow. They are getting paid, so its not an undue burden on their part, and frankly, you situation seems so typical, that I'm surprised that they don’t have support info all over the site on this issue.

Comment: Thanks frank. I decreased the security level to medium and problem solved.